Handling multiple IO blocking services using asyncio
This doesn't necessarily have to be a question about Python, it could rather be about asynchronous programming in general. To keep it short, I have an undefined number of objects where each executes its operation by running a function that essentially acts as an infinite loop (often contains while True). These functions, across multiple objects, execute in parallel (for now they don't share data between them but instead use either callbacks or send data to a third place without passing data backwards).
For example, let’s say I have objects of class Poller (poller1, poller2, poller3, and so on up to pollern) with a "read" function (contains infinite loop). Similarly, I have objects of class Listener (listener1, listener2, listener3, and so on up to listenern).
These functions use asyncio and asynchronous calls, and everything works as I intended. However, I'm not sure if this is the proper approach for this task or if it could be done more efficiently.
The function that runs my code looks like this:
async def loop(self):
    ...
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(device.read())
        for poller in self.pollers
    ]

    tasks.extend(
        [
            asyncio.create_task(listener.start())
            for listener in self.listeners
        ]
    )

    for task in tasks:
        await task

I simplified the code to focus on the core of the problem. My question is mainly about whether this is an adequate way to solve the problem and whether there are any obvious drawbacks that might make enhancing this functionality more difficult.

I am not sure what your specific concerns are, but I don't see any drawbacks to what you are doing. However, the code could be made somewhat more efficient (and clearer?) by using generator expressions instead of creating intermediate lists:
import itertools

...

async def loop(self):
    ...
    
    # Use generator expressions with itertools.chain
    
    readers = (
        asyncio.create_task(device.read())
        for poller in self.pollers)
    )
    
    listeners = (
        asyncio.create_task(listener.start())
        for listener in self.listeners
    )

    # Now iterate and create the tasks: 
    tasks = list(itertools.chain(readers, listeners))

    for task in tasks:
        await task

You might, perhaps, prefer this style:
...
async def loop():
    tasks = list(
        itertools.chain(
            (asyncio.create_task(device_read())  for poller in self.pollers),
            (asyncio.create_task(listener.start()) for listener in self.listeners),
        )
    )

    for task in tasks:
        await task

An actual example:
import asyncio
import itertools
import time

start_time = time.time()

async def reader(i):
    print(f'reader {i} started at time {time.time() - start_time}.')
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    print(f'reader {i} ended at time {time.time() - start_time}.')

async def listener(i):
    print(f'listener {i} started at time {time.time() - start_time}.')
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    print(f'listener {i} ended at time {time.time() - start_time}.')

async def loop():
    # Use generator expressions with itertools.chain

    readers = (
        asyncio.create_task(reader(i))
        for i in range(1, 4)
    )

    listeners = (
        asyncio.create_task(listener(i))
        for i in range(1, 4)
    )

    # Now iterate and create the tasks:
    tasks = list(itertools.chain(readers, listeners))

    for task in tasks:
        await task

asyncio.run(loop())

Prints:
reader 1 started at time 0.000997304916381836.
reader 2 started at time 0.000997304916381836.
reader 3 started at time 0.001997232437133789.
listener 1 started at time 0.001997232437133789.
listener 2 started at time 0.001997232437133789.
listener 3 started at time 0.001997232437133789.
reader 1 ended at time 1.0143013000488281.
listener 1 ended at time 1.0184080600738525.
listener 2 ended at time 2.006826162338257.
reader 2 ended at time 2.0074567794799805.
listener 3 ended at time 3.0023696422576904.
reader 3 ended at time 3.0023696422576904.


Thanks, that's a good suggestion. It would definitely make it a clearer and efficient. I will give it a try.

Your approach to handling multiple IO-blocking services using asyncio is fundamentally sound and aligns with best practices in asynchronous programming. Using asyncio.create_task to schedule read and start functions for your Poller and Listener objects is appropriate, as it allows these tasks to run concurrently without blocking the event loop. However, the issue with await task in your code is that it will block on the first task that doesn’t complete, preventing the rest from executing as intended. Instead, you should use await asyncio.gather(*tasks) to run all tasks concurrently, allowing for better scalability and easier handling of multiple tasks. Here's an improved version of your code:
async def loop(self):
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(poller.read())
        for poller in self.pollers
    ] + [
        asyncio.create_task(listener.start())
        for listener in self.listeners
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

This way, all tasks are properly managed, and any exceptions are propagated to the main event loop, ensuring robustness and maintainability.

Thanks, yes, tha's what I was thinking as well, I guess gather is a better solution in this case.

This answer is incorrect.  await task does NOT prevent other Tasks from executing; it prevents loop itself from proceeding until the awaited task finishes.  All the other Tasks continue, under control of the event loop.  Replacing the for task in tasks loop with gather, while standard practice and probably a slightly preferable coding style, will have almost no effect in this simple case.  The for task in tasks loop will not end until ALL the tasks are finished, which will have almost the same performance as await gather(*tasks) in this script.
